Why does my Azure Linked Service connection to Hubspot Public App fail?
I have created a public app in Hubspot and connected it to my Hubspot account (essentially followed this (only difference is that I create a public app since I believe this tutorial isn't up to date anymore):
https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/connecting-hubspot-azure-synapse-analytics-azure-data-factory/
Everything up until the last step (connecting to Azure via Linked Service) works perfectly.
When I click on "Test Connection" I receive the following error:

When I follow the link in the image (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-troubleshoot-guide#error-code-11000) I don't find a specific error code description.
When I try to connect to the private app and get a list of deals (I defined crm.objects.deals.read as the scope) I can successfully retrieve information, hence I don't think the connection on the Hubspot side is incorrect.

Can you provide your linked service configurations?
